# Calculating mean value in DataFrame using a mask

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following DataFrame:

```
   DATA            Price1            Price2               Price3
sys dis
27  0.8           43.89          83.06            33.75
    0.9           2.56           12.19            2.48
    1.0           42.28          1.87             1.93
    1.2           22.70          1.41             3.64
    1.4           20.38          1.36             2.02
28  0.8           22.024         35.47            16.96
    0.9           2.69           36.41            19.33
    1.0           59.30          8.90             11.41
    1.2           25.08          4.55             11.99
    1.4           26.85          3.30             7.37
    1.6           437.82         3.50             5.65
    1.8           55.21          2.91             1.84
    2.0           32.54          4.68             5.03
    2.5           52.91          5.42             6.58
```

I need to calculate `mean` Prices for `dis < 1.0` and seperately for `dis > 1.0`.

I've tried to create a mask function:

```
def mask(df):
        df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('dis').between(0.8,1.0), 'Price1'].mean()
        df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('dis').between(1.0,2.6), 'Price1'].mean()
         return df

print (df_new.ix[:,'Price1']).apply(mask)
```

Thought I am getting the following error :

> AttributeError: ("'Float64Index' object has no attribute 'between'").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use boolean comparators:

```
mean_low = df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('dis') < 1.0), 'Price1'].mean()
mean_high = df.loc[(df.index.get_level_values('dis') > 1.0), 'Price1'].mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

easiest solution is

```
df['price_low']=df.ix[df.reset_index()['dis'] < 1,'price']
df['price_high']=df.ix[df.reset_index()['dis']  > 1, 'price']

df.price_low.mean()
df.price_high.mean()
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
idx_s = df.index.to_series()
lvl1 = idx_s.str.get(0)
gt_1 = np.where(idx_s.str.get(1) > 1, 'GT_1', 'LE_1')
df.groupby([lvl1, gt_1]).mean()
```

[image]